# Android: BitmapFactory.decodeResource returns bitmap with larger file size

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm loading a `.jpg` from my `drawables-nodpi` folder via `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()` into my application - and I'm currently trying to deal with `OutOfMemoryExceptions`.

I found out that the returned file size of my bitmap is about 8MB, whereas my .jpg file is actually less than 1MB. The width/height haven't been changed, though.

Any solutions to this problem?

Comment: the bitmap needs width*height*4 bytes of ram

Comment: Well that's pretty awful since I need my bitmap to fill my whole screen (1920*1024)... And 8MB is quite a lot, considering that I have limited heap size & need to do some more memory-heavy operations in this app. I don't only want to use one bitmap on the screen

Comment: the only option is down sampling it

Comment: You mean scaling it down / using only half of its size (&quality)?

Comment: yes I do. Look for inSampleSize

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the only way :) I was hoping for some other tricks which don't result in losing quality of the image, but anyways. Better lower quality than not supporting a device with low memory heap. Thanks!